# Node.js setImmediate in a for loop

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use Graph API using Node.js to delete some users from a group.  The array `users` contains about 600 entries.  I got about 100 results from Facebook.  The remaining result is `undefined`

I use `setImmediate` to queue the request.

```
users = [1234234, 153223, ...];

var request = require('request');

const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'DQVJ0UT...';

var graphapi = request.defaults({
  baseUrl: 'https://graph.facebook.com',
  json: true,
  auth: {
    'bearer' : ACCESS_TOKEN
  }
});

function del(uid) {
  graphapi({
    url: '6803161/members',
    method: 'DELETE',
    qs: {
      member: uid
    }
  }, function(error,res,body) {
    console.log(body)
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  setImmediate(del, users[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setImmidiate` will not help here, because the response will arrive after the current loop end.

You need asyncronous processing. Simpliest way to make what you want with success is to use `async` library:

```js
const users = [1234234, 153223, ...];

const request = require('request');
const async = require('async');

const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'DQVJ0UT...';

var graphapi = request.defaults({
  baseUrl: 'https://graph.facebook.com',
  json: true,
  auth: {
    'bearer' : ACCESS_TOKEN
  }
});

function del(uid, cb) {
  graphapi({
    url: '6803161/members',
    method: 'DELETE',
    qs: {
      member: uid
    }
  }, function(error,res,body) {
    cb(error, body);
  });
}

async.map( users, del, (err, results) => {
   if (error) console.error(error);
   console.log(results);
});
```

Please note in my answer I am giving solution for correcting async flow, and i did not checked specific API calls implimentation with request provided in your snippet